# Given perpendicular unit vectors $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$, prove that the path $\vec{r}(t)=\sin(t)\vec{u}+\cos(t)\vec{v}$ is located on a sphere.

Tags: vectors

Let's say we have two constant and perpendicular unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$: $\vec{u},\vec{v}$.

> Prove that $\vec{r}(t)=\sin(t)\vec{u}+\cos(t)\vec{v}$ is located on a sphere. What is the origin of the sphere and what is the value of its radius?

My approach was to try to add the sine and cosine parts, but it didn't give me something useful. My second approach was to think about this problem in a geometrical way. I see that $\vec{r}(t)$ is a vector which acts like a radius vector of a sphere, because it is based on the sine and cosine. The center of the sphere is $(0,0,0)$ and its radius is 1.

But this assumption is not a proof. May you give me a hint about a right way to solve this kind of a problem?

Comment: The curve is a circle, so the solution is not unique.

Comment: Why do you say *origin* instead of *center* ?

Comment: Fixed, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recalling that $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ are perpendicular unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$, evaluate the dot product $\vec{r}(t)\cdot\vec{r}(t)$:
\begin{align}\|\vec{r}(t)\|^2&=\vec{r}(t)\cdot\vec{r}(t)=(\sin(t)\vec{u}+\cos(t)\vec{v})\cdot((\sin(t)\vec{u}+\cos(t)\vec{v})\\
&=\sin^2(t)\|\vec{u}\|^2+2\sin(t)\cos(t)\,\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}+\cos^2(t)\|\vec{v}\|^2.
\end{align}
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Looks interesting! But I don't understand why I need to use the dot product here?

Comment: It will turn out that $\|\vec{r}(t)\|^2$ is constant...

Comment: Yes, now it makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Dear downvoter, a (even short) feedback is welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Assume the center $\vec c$ and radius $r$. We must have

$$(\sin(t)\vec{u}+\cos(t)\vec{v}-\vec c)^2=r^2$$

or $$1+\|\vec c\|^2-2\sin(t)\,\vec u\cdot \vec c-2\cos(t)\,\vec{v}\cdot \vec c=r^2.$$

For this to hold for all $t$, we need $\vec c$ to be $c\,\vec u\times\vec v$, implying $r=\sqrt{c^2+1}$.